# how do I get all checkbox variables even if not checked from HTML to PHP?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, checked

I noticed that PHP seems to return only values of checked checkboxes. I would like to see a list of checkboxes, not just values of checked checkboxes. Is there a way to detect variables of unchecked boxes?

I asked because I want to be able to update settings. For example, I have a few options that are already checked but if an user decides to uncheck an option, I need to know that unchecked value so I can update the option to be disabled.

Comment: Hmm, if you are able to populate all the checkboxes, shouldn't you be able to know which are the non-checked ones based on those which are checked?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself.  I solved it by adding a duplicate `hidden` field with the same name.  When the browser sends this information, the second field overrides the first (so ensure that the `hidden` field comes first).

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar">
```

If the `checkbox` is not checked you get:

```
$_REQUEST[ 'foo' ] == ""
```

If the `checkbox` is checked you get:

```
$_REQUEST[ 'foo' ] == "bar"
```

Comment: It is very dependent on the implementation of the client.

Comment: Well, its part of the W3C spec.  Its also how Rails handles checkboxes if that's worth anything to you.

Comment: Simple and elegant. A very smart way of handling the situation.

Comment: This doesn't work in an Ajax implementation... I always get "0" even when I check and submit a checkbox that wasn't selected when the page loads. In other words, if I have three dynamically created checkboxes with the values 1,2,3 and 2 and 3 were checked by default... When I check box 1 and post with Ajax, I get 0. So, the hidden field overrides the checkbox value.

Comment: @PeterKovacs, **Is it** part of the W3C spec? Please cite.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set  Note the use of "in tree-order" and "append".

Comment: What if about `<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]">`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something that can be done purely in PHP.

Browsers only send information about checkboxes if they are checked, if you want to also send information about unchecked checkboxes, you'll have to add hidden fields in the form and use javascript to manage them.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this problem myself and I sorted it by updating all values in the database to unchecked then re-checking only the ones that are in the POST data, this works fine for me but might not be everyone's cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

A pure PHP implementation doesn't seem possible, you can try using jQuery/AJAX though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a 3 checkboxes you want to check, and update_settings is the name of your functions that take the checkbox name as a first argument and a bool value as a second one (activate or not).

Take the following snippet:

```
$checkboxes = array("checkbox1", "checkbox2", "checkbox3");
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox){
    $checked = isset($_POST[$checkbox]);
    update_settings($checkbox, $checked);
}
```

Althouth [Peter Kovacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944019/how-do-i-get-all-checkbox-variables-even-if-not-checked-from-html-to-php/1944065#1944065) solution it's going to work, I don't think it's practical since you can already check your variables using isset.