# Prevent submitting a radio group in a form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with some check boxes and a radio group, and simply removed the 'name' attribute from the check boxes to prevent them from being submitted. But radio groups need a name attribute for the client to know what belongs to each other. Can I prevent those radio buttons from being submitted with the form?

Comment: just put them outside of ``form``

Comment: Or [remove them on submission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008071/1612146)

Comment: ...or simply ignore them on the server side.

Comment: @doniyor That was simple. But worked fine in my case! Thanks... I belive submitting data that is ignored server side is not a good programming style but would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put those radio buttons outside of `<form>` like

```
<form>
  elements to submit 
</form>
<input type="radio" /> <!-- won't be submitted -->
```