# html form stopped working after adding javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Im working on a PHP application.
I had field form changing based on selected value. What I want is to change fields depending on privilege. 
The form was working before because i had only one type of user now since i have many i've add the script but users can't connect .

Here is the code

```
    <form action="accueil.php" method="post" name="connect" class="Style6">                     
    <select name="privilege" type="text" id="privilege" class="btn btn-default">
            <option value="choix">Choisir privilege</option>
            <option value="admin">Administrateur</option>
            <option value="client">Client</option>
            <option value="agent">Agent</option>
            <option value="credit_manager">Credit Manager</option>
            <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
            </select>
            <div id="admin" class="colors" style="display:none">
            <label>Connexion Administrateur  </label>
            <label>Login</label>
            <input name="login" type="text" id="login" class="input-block-level">
            <label>Mot de passe<a href="#" class="pull-right">&nbsp;Mots de passe oubli&eacute;</a> </label>
             <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" class="input-block-level">
             <label>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-default" ></button>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Se rappeler de moi</label>
            </div>
<div id="agent" class="colors" style="display:none">
            <label>Connexion Agent </label>
            <label>Login</label>
            <input name="login" type="text" id="login" class="input-block-level">
            <label>Mot de passe<a href="#" class="pull-right">&nbsp;Mots de passe oubli&eacute;</a> </label>
             <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" class="input-block-level">
             <label>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-default" ></button>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Se rappeler de moi
             </label>
            </div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-default"  value="Se Connecter">

                    </form>
```

And the jquery code is

```
$(function() {
        $('#privilege').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: @do you see any error?

Comment: have you included jquery?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/ is working fine.

Comment: what error you are getting in you console?

Comment: @RishiPrakash was right its working fine actually what you want ?

Comment: jquery code is working , but I'm talking about the submit in order to allow users authentification. I don't get errors

Answer (score 0):

The form will submit values regardless of whether the fields are displayed or not. Since you have multiple sets of fields with the same name, I think you might be overriding what you think you're submitting with blank values.

Comment: oK I see , can u tell me what I can I do ?

Comment: Here's a couple of suggestions as to what you could do http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008071/2463468