# Submit $modelValue instead of $viewValue in a traditional form post in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, http-post, masking

I'm using an [input mask directive](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) to force an input field to adjust to a fixed decimal format (dependent on the locale) in AngularJS 1.4.9.

This is my code:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post" name='myForm'>
            <input type="text" name="amount" ui-number-mask="2" ng-model="debit.amount">
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works as expected. The model holds the non formatted decimal value and the input field displays the formatted value.

[image: input-mask]

The problem arises when I hit <kbd>submit</kbd> and the form is submitted in a traditional POST fashion.

The server receives the following:

```
{ 
    "form": {
        "amount": "1,299.99", 
    },
}
```

instead of

```
{ 
    "form": {
        "amount": "1299.99", 
    },
}
```

I believe it's because it submits `$viewValue` instead of `$modelValue`.

**Workarounds I've tried**

1. **Use a hidden field** and set the `VALUE` attribute to the model value:

   ```
   <input type='hidden' name="amount_hidden" value="{{debit.amount}}">
   ```

   It works, but it's a bit of a hassle having to duplicate fields. See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewsuhj2p/7/).
2. **Submit using AngularJS' `$http.post()`** to mimic a traditional form post. This also works, but it's even more cumbersome than the previous. See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewsuhj2p/9/).

Is there an easier way to force the submission of `$modelValue`?

Comment: When you a traditional form submit, angular is not involved so the model values are not looked at. I think ng-submit is the correct way of submitting the forms with angular. Why do you think it is cumbersome?

Comment: @NMittal is right. A traditional form submit is taking whatever value is stored in the 'value' attribute on the input. Therefore `$viewValue` is what is reflecting in your request. Another solution would be to have an element positioned over the input displaying the `$modelValue` instead of the `$viewValue`.

Comment: While it's still a duplication of fields, you could stop the duplication of data being sent to the server. Remove the name attribute from the visible input field. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008071/1248889

Comment: @NMittal angular is indeed involved. That's the reason the `VALUE` attribute is ignored in `INPUT` fields. I think it's cumbersome because of the number of lines of code you have to write and maintain to be able to replicate a simple post action.

Comment: @SeanLarkin If it took the contents of the `VALUE` attribute, then the problem could be easily solved by setting this field. However, this attribute is ignored altogether in `INPUT` fields.

Comment: @InigoFlores value attribute is not ignored, it is the value attribute which you see in the text box which is = $viewValue. The HTML submit does not know what is in the $modelValue. And if you want to reduce lines of code with ng-submit, you can simply write a one liner: `$http.post("URL", {'debit.amount':$scope.debit.amount});` to achieve a simple post action

Comment: @NMittal See this [AngularJS - Value attribute on an input text box is ignored when there is a ng-model used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m/20522955). Also `$http.post("URL", {'debit.amount':$scope.debit.amount});` will not mimic a traditional form post.