# Is there a select-option version of div contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am inserting a small editable select-option in a html form. But i don't want to send it. So i need a select-option version of this

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Something like that

```
<div select="true">
  <div option="true"></div>
  <div option="true"></div>
  <div option="true"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a an easy way to achieve it without using js?

Comment: its not clear what you mean by select-option version. How would you like it to behave? Do you want to choose which div to be made editable?

Comment: I want the exact behavior of <select><option></select>. But i am writing it in form and i don't want to submit it

Comment: Do you want to have search in select options?

Comment: place the `<select>` outside the `<form>`. It won't be submitted with the form.

Comment: @lost_in_magento No. I just want it to be selectable

Comment: @user1599011 i need to put it inside form that's why i am saying. I thought maybe there is a way to do it in an easier way

Comment: Why does it need to be inside the form if you don't want to submit it?

Comment: @user1599011 i will use it to edit the value of textarea that is above it

Comment: check out this codepen to compare `datalist` with `select`: https://codepen.io/anweshgangula/pen/rNLEprj

Comment: @Kyoko Sasagava, That doesn't require the elements to be in the same form.

Comment: @user1599011 i know that. But i want it to show below the textarea tag. The form is long and i want to show which option belongs to which tag so i have to put it inside the form

Comment: Perhaps look into some css such that it's outside of the form structure but displays within.

Comment: Or exclude the name attribute and it won't be submitted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008035/stop-an-input-field-in-a-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: @user1599011 removing it from forms is easier i think. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have a normal select with some options but don't have a name attribute the selected option will not be submitted:

```
  <select>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  </select>
```

So the select can be contained within, and formatted as part of, the form element with no problem,

If you have a name attribute but with an empty name string then it seems browsers will submit the value but with nothing before the =